# Append to a string if result is not null in one line? (clean/good looking)

Tags: java, string, constructor, null

I have an object of with 5 internal string variables, but 3 of them are optional. I could create a constructor for each possible combination or I could call general constructor and pass it some empty strings. The later case is interesting to me, if I when calling the constructor I could do something like:

```
String a = "Mandatory";
...
String e = "" + getVariableE(); //getVariableX() could return null, 
                                //then it would be "".
                                //This is a "long" fetch statement.

new objectA(a, b, c, d, e);
```

Another other option:

```
String d = "";
String e = "";
if(getVariableD!=null)  //Remember pretty long fetch statement (ugly looking)
     d = getVariableD();
if(getVariableE!=null)
    e = getVariableE();

new objectA(a, b, c, d, e);
```

I do not see a away to use multiple constructors without the use of multiple if statements.

```
new objectA(a, b, c);
new objectA(a, b, c, d)
```

I think the constructor may not be a factor here, but only the way the lines are set to "" or to something; nevertheless, I left it in case i miss something.

This is the simple objectA class

```
public class objectA {
String a; //Needed
String b; //Needed
String c; //Optional
String d; //Optional
String e; //Optional
/*
 * Possible constructor
*/
    void object(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {
    this.a = a;
    ...
    this.e = e;
    }
```

Note: getVariableX() gets an attribute from an XML file, so I could force that it MUST contain a string, but I do not think this would be nice. Better give flexibility to the XML file.

Comment: `this.d = d == null ? getD() : d`

Comment: This was going to be included in Java 7 with the Elvis operator, but never made the cut: http://blogs.infosupport.com/java-7-and-the-elvis-operator/

Comment: If you cannot use `""` i.o.  `null` you could make your own OptionalString or use a static function `StringUtils.defaultString(String)` from [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

Comment: @nhahtdh Do you meant to put that in the constructor? It doesnt have access to the getD() or did you mean something like String d = getD()==null ? getD() : ""; ?

Comment: @Juan: I didn't try to understand your code. I only demonstrate the use of ternary operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `getVariableD()` returns a String, you can also use the `Strings.nullToEmpty()` method from [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#nullToEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) to avoid having to type (and evaluate) getVariableD() twice.

Of course, you can write a similar utility method for arbitrary Objects:

```
/** Returns {@code obj.toString()}, or {@code ""} if {@code obj} is {@code null}. */
static String safeToString(@Nullable Object obj) {
  return obj == null ? "" : obj.toString();
}
```

and then do:

```
String d = safeToString(getVariableD());
```

Comment: Both answers are pretty good, but i think this one really catches the essence of the answer I wanted. (Not sure why I didn't think about creating a method

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Optional class included with Java 8.

```
this.d = Optional.ofNullable(d).orElse("");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(getVariableD!=null) {
    d = getVariableD();
}
```

Can be converted to a ternary operator:

```
d = getVariableD != null ? getVariableD() : "";
```

Note: you should always prefer code readability over conciseness.

The [Elvis operator](http://blogs.infosupport.com/java-7-and-the-elvis-operator) was syntactic sugar that was proposed for Java 7 but never made the cut.

Comment: I agree. I think my desire for shortness was more on the if statements if multiple constructors was the better choice (which I had before). Between the short hand if or the long one, i do prefer the long one.